# Does QuickTime .mov format support any standardized means of encryption?

Tags: quicktime, multimedia, drm

Does QuickTime .mov format support any standardized means of encryption? I did not find anything in the [standard](https://developer.apple.com/standards/qtff-2001.pdf). For example is it possible to encrypt the track sample data with lets say AES, put that information and some atom and then the player would ask you to enter the key for decryption. As far as I am aware MP4 at least has some [standardized](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec23001-7%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf) boxes for this purpouse.